# Only GET requests are returned in lighthouse devtools network records

Tags: lighthouse

I am trying to run certain audits on the network requests made by a web page during loading and below is my sample code for the audit. I am facing a problem that all the network records returned by the lighthouse are only for GET requests. Is there any way to get records for POST, PUT, etc

sample code:

```
class NetworkAudit extends Audit {
  static get meta() {
    return {
      id: 'network-audit',
      title: 'Network analysis',
      failureTitle: 'Custom network stats failing',
      description: 'Custom network stats ',
      requiredArtifacts: ['devtoolsLogs'],
    };
  }

  static async audit(artifacts, context) {
    const devtoolsLog = artifacts.devtoolsLogs[Audit.DEFAULT_PASS];

    const requests = await NetworkRecords.request(devtoolsLog, context);
    for(request of requests ){
       console.log(request.requestMethod)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around for a while, I found a way to capture all the network requests and created an npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/lighthouse-network-gatherer

After package installation, use is very simple and here is a sample code

```
class  NetworkLogs  extends  networkGatherer{
  constructor(){
    super()
  }
}
module.exports = NetworkLogs
```